# How do you use socket.io within electron?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron

I am trying to implement socket.io within an electron app. Following previous advice on a question I followed this chat app example https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and then tried to turn it into an electron app. However it is like the functionality doesn't exist now, what am I doing wrong? The app launches but I only see the front end I can type and submit but nothing comes back. The code is as follow

main.js

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    
    function createWindow () {
      const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
        }
      })
    
      win.loadFile('index.html')
    }
    
    app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
    
    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
      if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
    
    app.on('activate', () => {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
      }
    })
```

index.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg)
    });
});
```

index.html

```
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value) {
                socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
                input.value = '';
            }
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = msg;
            messages.appendChild(item);
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

If I do node index.js it functions perfectly (I took the listen on port 3000 out in this question) However npm start to use as an electron app does not. Please Help!!!!!

Comment: Just to make sure, you're running `npm start` while `node index.js` is also running? If `node index.js` isn't running then there won't be a socket.io server to connect to.

Comment: I have tried this and no doesn't work, Do i need to specify a port in my main.js too?